# How to change the content value of iconmoon font?

Tags: css, fonts, embed, font-face

I've used icomoon font on my menu. I could not change the font icon of PICTURE menu. Initially it was BLOG icon. And now I need to change it with the icon of PICTURE (CAMERA). How to change the content value of BLOG into PICTURE?

## HTML PART

```
<nav id="menu" class="nav">                 
<ul>
<li> 
<a href="#"> <span class="icon"> <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-home"></i> </span>
<span>Home</span>
</a>
</li>
<li> 
<a href="#"> <span class="icon"> <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-portfolio"></i></span>
<span>About Us</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"> <span class="icon"> <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-camera"></i></span>
<span>PICTURE</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

## CSS PART

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
src: url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src: url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
};

.icon-camera, .icon-home, .icon-portfolio {
font-family: 'icomoon';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.icon-camera:before { content: "\e600"; }
.icon-home:before { content: "\e002"; }
.icon-portfolio:before { content: "\e003";}

a, li { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in fact very easy to change icons in CSS. You can have your own icon classes, for example FontAwesome uses 2 classes, first `fa` to set default attributes and second for icon content, like `fa-home` for home, so you call it `class="fa fa-home"`. Why is it better? You don't need to maintain that default attribute part, where with every added icon, you need to add it to that list.
I would suggest to change this:

```
.icon-camera, .icon-home, .icon-portfolio {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

to this:

```
.im {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

and use it with content classes like `class="im icon-camera"`:

```
.icon-camera:before { content: "\e600"; }
.icon-home:before { content: "\e002"; }
.icon-portfolio:before { content: "\e003";}
```

And if you want to change icon, just change the `content` part, where unicode value can be found on their [website](https://icomoon.io#preview-free) by inspecting icon's code and looking at class name, where picture/camera has class `.free-uniE90F` so your code for camera will be `content: "\e90f";`